# Chat flag indicator may be getting shown to unqualified users

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, chat, user-interface, flagging

I'm pretty sure I don't have enough SU rep to be seeing chat flags. However, I saw the "flagged post" indicator when I logged in to chat just now. Clicking on it produced this screen:

[image: flags page indicating that one flag exists but reading "there are no flags to display"]

I'm guessing the "display flags" logic is okay, but the "display flag indicator" logic isn't.

Comment: Chat flags have a habit of... misbehaving. One of the devs will hopefully check this out.

Comment: This has happened to me as well.  I just ignore it ATM.  It appears that chat is just plain a bit.... buggy.

Comment: I don't think chat looks at reputation of individual sites - you get privileges based on total network rep.

Comment: Interesting, @Wil. I'm at about 7k if you don't count SO and MSO, which still shouldn't be enough to see flags. With SO and MSO, I'm well over 10k. Perhaps they do count SO and MSO, even though those sites have their own separate chat.

Answer (score 4):

You have over 30k reputation on chat.se (just visit your chat profile, the number is right there). On chat.se, what counts is network-wide reputation (and this has always been that way).